# unable to add,edit,delete content types in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, commerce

I'm unable to add, edit, delete content types and content also in Drupal 7, the button links are not working. If I click add, edit, delete button below an error happens. What could be wrong here?

[image: content type page]

[image: Error page when I click add,edit,delete then coming below error]

[image: error log section]

[image: clean urls page before test -admin/config/search/clean-urls]

[image: after test clean urls page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following steps.

1. Make sure clean URLs working first. If you need any help for clean URL visit this [link](https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls#enabling-7)
2. Try clear cache and then disable all contributed modules. I see there is a problem due to commerce line items module. Disable all contributed modules. Don't disable core modules.
3. Clear cache and check.

Tell me in comments if you still face problem.

Comment: Hi Himanshu getting same error.

Comment: Clean URL's started working ? Attach screenshot of page admin/config/search/clean-urls

Comment: I see clean URLs are not enabled @Parvateesam. Read the doc I gave you. Or check with your server admin. Few things I'll tell you if you are on ubuntu , run this command on terminal " sudo a2enmod rewrite " and tell me what it says. Also make sure you have .htaccess file in drupal root folder.

Comment: Yes i'm using linux Mint ,I run the command on terminal " sudo a2enmod rewrite " still clean url's test failed

Comment: create virtualhost for your site or add " <Directory /var/www/drupal>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>" in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf, replace /var/www/drupal with your installation root. then " sudo service apache2 restart " in terminal

Comment: Hi i have created virtualhost but still i'm unable add content to related content type getting same error and clean url's check box not appear still .@Himanshu Pathak

Comment: are you having AllowOverride All  in virtual host conf file ?

Comment: Yes,in live all are working fine i'm creating,editing content types fine but problem in local machine @ Himanshu Pathak

Comment: can you disable all contrib modules through drush and try clearing cache . or truncate all db table which start with "cache"

Comment: Thank You issue is fixed in my local machine.@Himanshu Pathak

Comment: which one worked for you ? anyways congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try increasing your `max_allowed_packet` setting in MySQL.

Open `my.cnf` file & update `max_allowed_packet = 16M` or more

**Or**

In `settings.php` and add a line inside file :

`$conf['error_level'] = 1;`

Comment: Hi NishantP i done same thing in my local same error coming

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, i can sense you installed commerce module, i disabled the commerce report module which causing some problem. Try disable that commerce report module, If you can go to module page, then try disable in phpmyadmin in "system" table

Answer (score 0):

I think you uninstalled the commerce module and now you want to remove the related content-types. Right?

You probably need to re-install drupal commerce, then remove the undesired content types and uninstall drupal commerce again.

Comment: No,I’m unable to uninsulated commerce module because of it is depends on other modules ,if i uninsulated then i'm facing other issues. but in live there is no issues regarding my question ,i'm facing this issue in local server,and i took backup from live and again configured in my local after open site from local i'm not see the home page it's showing blank page.i'm new to drupal help me@Bram de Leeuw

Comment: A blank (home)page can mean lots of things but it's usually a PHP error. Check your Drupal logs or your server logs and you will probably find the reason for the blank homepage.